# Error with WCF. Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, tfs, wshttpbinding

I'm new to building Web Services and WCF in general, although I've done well so far I've ran into The following issue issue I can't seem to get past.

Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

I have my app.config set up as such

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WcfSoapServiceBinding">
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfSoapServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfSoapServiceBehavior" name="WcfSoapService.Service1">
            <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfSoapServiceBinding"
              contract="WcfSoapService.IService1" />
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I set security mode to "None" so it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS and I also set the httpGetEnabled to true. I've tried some different options I've found online for some time, but none have helped so far. I'm using Ewald Hofman's example on how to use WCF to subscribe to TFS.

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx

I feel like I am close but this is the one thing I can't get past. My ultimate goal is to take the Soap Request from TFS and parse through its data. Being new to WCF and Web servers I'm unsure on what this error is actually telling me is wrong as well. So I have two questions.

1) What does this error mean is wrong? More specifically what does "Registered base address schemes are []" mean.

2) How could I go about fixing the error?

Comment: You aren't specifying an address for your endpoint - are you hosting your service in IIS or self hosting?

Answer (score 0):

In your service section add base address or add address element for your endpoint.

```
 <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfSoapServiceBehavior" name="WcfSoapService.Service1">

         <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8182/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

            <endpoint address=""
 binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfSoapServiceBinding"
              contract="WcfSoapService.IService1" />
          </service>
```

Comment: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Comment: Add another endpoint to expose metadata about your service.  <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />

Comment: Yea same error unfortunately, but I'll try some other endpoints as well as I haven't tried this solution yet.